# c# String concatenation of string property on viewModel List object using linq to be displayed on a MVC View

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have looked on SO for a solution to my problem, but have not seen anything that comes close.

I have an object:

```
public class MyTestObject()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public IList<Event> Events {get;set;
}
```

and

```
public class Event()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Type {get;set;}
    public string EventName {get;set;}
}
```

What I am trying to do is concatenate the EventName properties from the Event class into a single string separated with a newline.

```
string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyTestObject.Events.Where(x => 
x.Type == 99).Select(x => x.Reference));
```

This produces a concatenated string, but the newline is not recognised. The string is to be displayed in a div on an MVC page.

I have replaced Environment.Newline for `<br/>`, which just adds the text string `<br/>` in between the joined strings.

Example

```
text1<br />text2
```

Next I tried:

```
string test = string.Join("", MyTestObject.Events.Where(x => 
x.Type == 99).Select(x => x.Reference + " Boo"));
```

Which gave me:

```
text1Bootext2Boo
```

So logic prevailed and I tried

```
string test = string.Join("", MyTestObject.Events.Where(x => 
x.Type == 99).Select(x => x.Reference + Environment.NewLine));
```

Then I looked at the html to see that a new line had been added, but not displayed in the browser.

Should I be using a particular style on the div to make it see the line break?

Comment: I would assume that the newline it is returning is `/r/n` where as html wants something like `<br/>`. I would try replacing `Environment.NewLine` with that and seeing if that works.

Comment: wouldn't that be replace with `"\r\n"` or actually using the html page break `"<br />"`

Comment: _Should I be using a particular style on the div to make it see the line break?_ Yes its `white-space: pre-line`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace in HTML is ignored. Therefore, returning a newline character in your string will only affect the source, not the actual rendered HTML. If you want the line break rendered, you must use `<br />`, as you've also tried. However, your problem there is that Razor escapes HTML in strings by default. To avoid that behavior, you need to use `Html.Raw`:

```
string test = string.Join("<br />", MyTestObject.Events.Where(x => x.Type == 99).Select(x => x.Reference));
```

Then:

```
@Html.Raw(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `MyTestObject` is a `list`, try this:

```
var eventNameArray = MyTestObject.SelectMany(x => x.Events)
                                 .Select(x => x.EventName)
                                 .ToArray();
```

or if you need distinct values

```
var eventNameArray = MyTestObject.SelectMany(x => x.Events)
                                 .Select(x => x.EventName)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToArray();
```

Then you could `join` the result into a single string. If you need `<br/ >` just replace by it. `\n` is not `<br />` and html require `<br />` to break lines.

```
var eventNames = string.Join("<br />", eventNameArray);
```